# How to write a second thread which listens to incoming signals?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a question concerning the Slot-/Signal-architecture in Qt. For my project I have separate functions for:

a) GUI
b) controlling external devices

Now I want to have function b) constantly listening to Signals sent from a) on specific slots. But this listening should not influence the GUI thread, e.g. I want to continue with my work there.

Thus I had the idea to move the function b) to a separate thread. But my problem is that I do not know how to create the `run`-function in this thread. It should start with my program (no problem), and it should constantly listen to incoming signals and then run the function which is connected to this signal.

Would a simple `while(1)` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt makes this pretty straightforward. I would not advise overriding `run()` for this as it is not necessary - also it is not as flexible or easy to implement, and has a few caveats regarding object creation.

Instead, just create a thread then move your listening object to it. For example:

```
// 'this' as parent means thread will terminate automatically when 'this'
// is deleted, you have other options here, of course.
QThread *thread = new QThread(this);

// Create your object (or just use an existing one). Note new object initially
// lives on current thread. Note also it does not have a parent. Objects with
// parents cannot be moved to other threads explicitly.
MyObject *object = new MyObject(); // Assuming MyObject is a QObject.

// Now move the object to the new thread.
object->moveToThread(thread);

// And, you'll want to make sure the object is deleted when the thread ends.
connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), object, SLOT(deleteLater()));
connect(thread, SIGNAL(terminated()), object, SLOT(deleteLater())); // just in case

// Finally, start the thread:
thread->start();
```

That's all you need to do! Now the thread is running, with its own event loop, and signals connected to the object's slots will be queued and run on that thread<sup>†</sup>.

Note that if your object's constructor creates any QObjects of its own, it should set itself as those objects' parent accordingly. Qt will automatically move all child objects of your object to the thread as well when you do `object->moveToThread()`.

You can move as many objects as you want to a given `QThread`, it isn't limited to just one.

To explicitly end the thread, and clean up the object, call `thread->exit()` or just delete the thread. Again, though, since we made `this` a parent of the `QThread` in the above example, you really don't need to do any cleanup at all.

By the way, if you have some initialization or other tasks that your object should perform on the thread when the thread is started, you can also use the thread's `started()` signal:

```
connect(thread, SIGNAL(started()), object, SLOT(initializeWhatever()));
```

---

Note, of course, that any objects used in the above way must be subclasses of `QObject`. This is where e.g. `moveToThread()` and `deleteLater()` are, and is also required for proper handling of slots:

```
class MyObject : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyObject (QObject *parent = 0);
signals:
    ...
public slots:
    ...
};
```

The easiest way, really, to set this up is in QtCreator, right click, add a new class, and choose `QObject` as a base there. Qt will set up a template header and source file for you.

---

<sup>†</sup> Unless the connection type is [`DirectConnection`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum), but by default it is not.

Comment: Can I move a whole class to a second thread, too? E.g. that all functions from this class are executed in this thread?

Comment: @arc_lupus You move an *instance* of a class to another thread (e.g. you can have 5 `MyObject`s on 5 separate threads if you want). You can't just make some sort of default thread that new `MyObject`s magically move themselves to. You have to either create them then move them to the thread; or create them *from* the thread (e.g. if you move a `MyObject` to a thread, then create a new `MyObject` *from one of that first object's slots on the new thread*, then the new `MyObject` will also live on the new thread -- objects initially live on the thread that `new` is called from).

Comment: Yes, I meant that I have something like `class A: {...}, A a; a->moveToThread();`.

Comment: @arc_lupus Sure; that's like the example above. You have a class `A`. You have an instance of that class, `a`. You move that instance to a thread. No problem with that, that's how you do it! Just remember to connect the thread to `a->deleteLater()` so your object is deleted when the thread is destroyed.

Comment: The problem is (I just tested it) that I get the error: `a has no member named "moveToThread". Did I forget something?

Comment: @arc_lupus Ah! You did. It seems I made an incorrect assumption about your code. I even thought of mentioning that but didn't. Your object must derive from `QObject` - it needs to do this to have slots anyways. I will update example. I assumed you already knew that.

Comment: @arc_lupus Don't forget to use the `Q_OBJECT` macro (shown in edit above) if you are creating the source files by hand. If you use QtCreator to make a new class and choose the QObject base there, though, it will add this for you and you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: I already included that macro, because I derived that class in my first try from QThread.